# my css code "overflow:hidden" doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make carousel

I develop with wsl2 ubunto
using python django

and this is my file
https://github.com/YEONGORI/ShoppingMalll-Project.git

I tried using overflow-x: hidden instead of overflow: hidden

```css
.main {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 640px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slide_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.slide_container input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 640px;
  height: 430px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slide_container">
  <!-- radio buttons -->
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
  <!-- slide images -->
  <div class="slide first">
    <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test1.PNG' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test2.PNG' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test3.PNG' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test4.PNG' %}">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to a [mcve] using images from placeholder.com or lorempixel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have added `overflow: hidden;` to the class `.slider` Where are your slider container `.slide_container`  is outside it.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the universal selector and you should also add the content of your `.main` class too. As they are for resetting the browser style.

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvzEKJR